# Passing multiple values with same name using @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having issues trying to pass multiple values for a request param, for example.

**I currently have this**
`http://localhost:8080/api/posts/search?brand=audi`

**But would like something like this**
`http://localhost:8080/api/posts/search?brand=audi&brand=bmw&brand=xxx`

I'm using `@RequestParam(required = false) List<String> brand,`, but when I call a method in my Service class to find the values, I'm not sure how to be able to get all the values from the RequestParam, ie. brand=audi&brand=bmw, I don't know how to get all of those when passing the arugment to my findAllByBrand() method.

```
// When calling this from my Controller, how do i ensure i capture all possible request params
pageTuts = postService.findAllByBrand(pagingSort, ?);
```

**From Service Class**

```
    public Page<Post> findAllByBrand(Pageable pageable, String brand) {
        Page<Post> page = postRepository.findAllByBrand(pageable, brand);

        if(page.isEmpty()) throw new PostNotFoundException("There are no matching records..");
        return page;

    }
```

Same with my Repository Interface, I currently have this.

```
    @Query("From Post p WHERE p.brand LIKE %:brand% ORDER BY p.price ASC")
    Page<Post> findAllByBrand(Pageable pageable, String brand);
```

Comment: Now if only the query language had an option to select something that matches something IN a collection... `findAllByBrandIn`. The `Pageable` must be last not first.

Comment: Your URL will look like this: `http://localhost:8080/api/posts/search?brand=audi,bmw,xxx` so coma separated. It will collect as any `Collection` type.

Comment: @LenglBoy Managed to get it working using the Query method that M. Deinum said, thanks again